# Use a loop to replicate the value of a cell into multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need to figure out a way of copying the value of a cell to other cells in the worksheet. I'm thinking of a loop but I don't know how to go about doing this.

For example, I want my loop to start from cell "B16", going through every cell in column B till it gets to a cell with the value "Automation Table:". In between that, if a cell contains any value/string then it should move 5 columns from its current position and assign the value "Hello" to that cell.

This is what I currently have but its not working as it should:

```
Sub TC_data()
  Dim x As String
  Dim found As Boolean
  ' Select first line of data.
  Range("B16").Select
  ' Set search variable value.
  x = "*string*"
  ' Set Boolean variable "found" to false.
  found = False
  ' Set Do loop to stop at a non-empty cell.
  Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "Automation Table:"
  'Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
     ' Check active cell for search value.
     If ActiveCell.Value = x Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Hello"
        found = True
        Exit Do
     End If
     ' Step down 1 row from present location.
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop
End Sub
```

It ignores every other statement and just goes to the cell with the value "Automation Table:"

Comment: I'm afraid your single example of copying C3 to G16 does not adequately explain why the values were copied nor what cells to loop through looking for some unknown condition.

Comment: Sorry if the previous post wasn't explanatory enough. I have edited the post. Please your help/suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using `.Select` in favor of direct cell and range referencing wherever possible.

```
Sub B2AutoTable()
    Dim b As Long, bat As Long, x As String
    bat = Application.Match("Automation Table:", Columns(2), 0) - 1
    x = LCase("*String*")
    For b = 16 To bat
        'this option is for a pattern match to x
        If LCase(Cells(b, "B").Value) Like x Then Cells(b, "G") = "ahoj"
        'the next line is for any value or string
        'If CBool(Len(Cells(b, "B").Value)) Then Cells(b, "G") = "ahoj"
    Next b
End Sub
```

I've given you two options as your description seems to differ from the code segment that you posted.

This assumes that the *Automation Table:* value is somewhere in column B, preferably below row 16. If that is not an absolute certainty, you will have to work up some error control. If you have trouble with that, post back with your attempt and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made little changes to your block of code and it worked just as I wanted it to. Really appreciate your help.